# How to use expand and collapse items in gridview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, webforms

How to use collapse and expand in each gridview item on selection of radio button in front of gridview items ..

if radio button in gridview item one is selected then the record will be expand to down to show more details ...

i'm using vb.net

Comment: do you want it on client side or in serverside

Comment: You might want to play with this: http://www.progtalk.com/viewarticle.aspx?articleid=54

Answer (score 0):

See the demo here. 
This website aspsnippets saves me a lot of time

[ASPSnippets Gridview expand and collapse](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Nested-GridViews-GridView-inside-GridView-with-Expand-and-Collapse-feature.aspx?&sa=U&ei=I0HRUonsG7Oo0wWU1IDADA&ved=0CFMQFjAI&usg=AFQjCNGtKMvOr-SNCPIWIi9N-_tzH1dK5A)

the HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"
    DataKeyNames="CustomerID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderId" HeaderText="Order Id" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Date" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

VB.net CODE

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        gvCustomers.DataSource = GetData("select top 10 * from Customers")
        gvCustomers.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Private Shared Function GetData(query As String) As DataTable
    Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = query
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                Using ds As New DataSet()
                    Dim dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    Return dt
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
</script>
```